# Using Eigen::Map with array of structs

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

Given an array of structs, how can I use Eigen to, for example, calculate the mean of all Foo.b?

```
struct Foo {
        int a;
        double b;
        char c;
}

std::vector<Foo> foos;
// push_back some Foos
```

From the documentation, I think I should be able to do this using an Eigen::Map and setting the stride appropriately, I just can't seem to figure out exactly what it needs to be. I think it should be something like:

```
using namespace Eigen;
double* bPtr = foos.data() + offsetof(struct Foo, b); // casts omitted for brevity
Map<ArrayXd, Unaligned, InnerStride<sizeof(Foo)>> bMap(bPtr, foos.size());
double mean = bMap.mean();
```

Relevant documentation here: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strides in Eigen are always considered as multiple of the size of the Scalar, i.e., you need to write:

```
using namespace Eigen;
Map<ArrayXd, Unaligned, InnerStride<sizeof(Foo)/sizeof(double)> >
   bMap(&foos[0].b, foos.size());
double mean = bMap.mean();
```

(Make sure `foos` is not empty before doing `&foos[0].b`)

This happens to work, since `double` (usually) has an alignment of 8 bytes, i.e., `Foo` will have padding bytes before `b` and after `c` so that `sizeof(Foo)` is guaranteed to be a multiple of `sizeof(double)`. Add a static assertion, if you want to be sure.

Usage demo: https://godbolt.org/z/aM-veN

Warning: This won't work for `std::complex<double>` unless you somehow make sure that the size of your struct is a multiple of 16 (or a multiple of 8 for `std::complex<float>`)